# Returning a function pointer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a url builder similar to the one in asp mvc except our methods are frequently changing parameters and breaking pages.

Does anyone know if it's possible to coerce c# into allowing event like syntax to be returned from a delegate like this:

```
new UrlBuilder2<FakeController>(x => { return x.ActionWithInt; });
```

The class would be similar to this:

```
public class UrlBuilder<TController>
{
    public UrlBuilder2(Func<TController, TType> action)
    {
    }
}
```

Basically I want to know what Type to use for TType. Or if it's at all possible.

Edit -
I would (if possible) like to use just the method, similar to how you would assign an event ( `clickEvent =+ myMethod;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but assuming you want to generate link simlar to this:

```
MyForm/MyMethod.aspx
```

based on WebForm (or any other class) like this:

```
public class MyForm {
  public void MyMethod() {
    // Something here
  }
  public void MethodWithParams(int i, string str) {
    // Something here
  }
}
```

You can use this builder (test included):

```
class UrlBuilder2<T> {
    private readonly Expression<Func<T, object>> callExpression;

    public UrlBuilder2(Expression<Func<T,object>> callExpression) {
        this.callExpression = callExpression;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        MethodCallExpression call = (MethodCallExpression) callExpression.Body;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}/{1}.aspx", call.Object.Type.Name, call.Method.Name);
        var delimiter = "?";
        var formalParams = call.Method.GetParameters();
        for (int i = 0; i < formalParams.Length; i++) {
            var actual = call.Arguments[i];
            if (actual == null)
                continue; // Do not put NULL to QueryString
            var formal = formalParams[i].Name;
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}={2}", delimiter, formal, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(actual.ToString()));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

[Test]
public void CanBuildUrlByClassAndMethodName() {
    var str = new UrlBuilder2<MyForm>(c => c.MyMethod()).ToString();
    str.Should().Be.EqualTo("MyForm/MyMethod.aspx");
}

[Test]
public void CanBuildUrlByMethodWithParams() {
    var str = new UrlBuilder2<MyForm>(c => c.MethodWithParams(2, "hello")).ToString();
    str.Should().Be.EqualTo("MyForm/MyMethod.aspx?i=2&str=hello");
}
```

All this will allow you to keep the links type-safe and refactoring advantages will be leveraged.
You will probably need to enhance the UrlBuilder2 but this should get you started.

---

If you just want to use name of a method to generate links you can do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public void MyMethod() {}
}

class UrlBuilder3<T> {
    Expression<Func<T, Action>> info;
    public UrlBuilder3(Expression<Func<T, Action>> info) {
        this.info = info;                
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        UnaryExpression exp = (UnaryExpression)info.Body;
        MethodCallExpression createDelegate = (MethodCallExpression)exp.Operand;
        // 0-Action,1-x,2-Delegate as Constant
        ConstantExpression methodArgument = (ConstantExpression)createDelegate.Arguments[2];

        MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo)methodArgument.Value;
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}.aspx", typeof(T).Name, method.Name);
    }
}

[Test]
public void UrlByDelegate() {
    new UrlBuilder3<MyClass>(x => x.MyMethod).ToString()
        .Should().Be.EqualTo("MyClass/MyMethod.aspx");
}
```

The tricky thing is correctly resolving the Expression tree. The code above works for this particular sample, but you will need to check it works for all your cases.

Comment: With this, if I add a parameter to MyMethod then it will still break everywhere thats using an expression to link to it. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No. It won't even compile then.

I added how to pass parameters to query string from method.

Comment: This is essentially what the existing URl builder does. I would (if possible) like to use just the method, similar to how you would assign an event ( clickEvent =+ myMethod;)

Comment: I added another sample for that. Hope that is what you need.

Comment: But. This is exactly what you have asked and what you showed in your example. If you want to pass the parameters, I already provided the solution earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function pointer aka a delegate in c# as below.

```
public delegate int mydelegate(string s);
public class Test
{
    mydelegate MyFunc(string s)
    {
        return (astring => astring.Length + s.Length);
    }
}
```

This would allow you to attach the output of the function to an event.

```
var test = new Test();
someevent += test.MyFunc("this is a test");
```

Assuming that someevent took a function with the same signature as the delegate.

Comment: This would require a delegate for every possible controller action, so not very elegant.

Comment: You can create various delegate signatures via generics i.e 
 public delegate T myreturningdelegate<T>();